# Titled & Untitled Questions in same document

Tags: exam

I need to have sections in an exam I am writing. The first 10 questions are multiple choice, which I would like to number simply 1-10.  For the extended response, I would like to title the questions.  Is there a way to do this in the exam class?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you read section 4.5 (Titled questions) of the documentation?

Answer (score 14):

This is described in the documentation: You can use `\titledquestion` to assign a title to your question. In order for this title to be used in the question section, you also need to redefine the `\qformat`. The format changes only apply to the questions that come after the `\qformat` command, so you could first have the normal questions, then issue a `\qformat` to get the titles. To revert back to the simple style, you can use `\noqformat`.

Here's a simple example:

[image: Exam with titled question]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[1]
What if I say I'm not like the others?
\begin{choices}
\choice You're the pretender
\choice I will never surrender
\end{choices}

\qformat{\thequestion. \textbf{\thequestiontitle} \hfill (\thepoints)}

\titledquestion{Complicated Long Question}[10] Identify all known unknowns and embrace complexity.

\noqformat
\question[1] Are you happy this is over?
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am ok having either titled questions or untitled questions.  I would like to have both in the one document.  What I was meaning to ask was: Can I just set titled questions for a specific section?

Comment: @user10082: The `\qformat` only applies to the questions that follow, so you can change the format at the beginning of the section. To remove the format, you can say `\noqformat` at the end of the section. I've edited my answer to give an example.

Comment: @cmhughes Possible answer might have been *No one knows* - Queens of the Stone Age.

Comment: I overlooked `qformat` in the manual. Thanks for mentioning it

Answer (score 0):

You could also define a flexible version of `qformat` using the `ifthen` package so that you can mix titled and untitled questions in the same document without worrying about order or redefining `qformat` multiple times:

```
\usepackage{ifthen}
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion 
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\thequestion}{\thequestiontitle}}
        {} % equality means title unset: do nothing
        {~(\thequestiontitle)} % there's a title, print it
    \hfill
    } % end textbf
}
```

Small working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{exam}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\qformat{\textbf{Question \thequestion 
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\thequestion}{\thequestiontitle}}
        {} % equality means title unset: do nothing
        {~(\thequestiontitle)} % there's a title, print it
    \hfill
    } % end textbf
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\titledquestion{I'm important enough to have a title} What is the meaning of life?

\question 2+2=5 ?

\titledquestion{Me too} Solve any of the millenium problems.

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]